# comparing length of sublists in a list F#

Tags: f#

I'm new to F#, and currently working on a problem where I'm trying to compare the length of sublists inside a list, and returning a boolean.

The program is also supposed to return "false" in case any of the sublists are empty. However as I've been progressing I haven't been able to solve my current problem, even though I somehow see what is wrong (this linked to my experience in the F# language thus far). Hopefully someone can lend me a hand, so I can quickly move on to my next project.

My program so far is as follows:

```
let projectOne (initList: int list list) =
let mutable lst = initList.[0].Length
let mutable lst1 = ""
let n = initList.Length
for i=1 to n-1 do
    if lst = 0 || initList.[i].Length = 0 then
        lst1 <- "false"
    elif lst <> initList.[i].Length then
        lst1 <- "false"
    elif
        lst = initList.[i].Length then 
        lst1 <- "true"
lst1

printfn "The sublists are of same lenght: %A" (projectOne [[1;2;3;4];[4;5;6];[6;7;8;9];[5;6;7;8]])
```

The way I see it is, that right now I am comparing [0] with  [i] incrementing with each iteration in my loop, this causes a problem as for the print example, I end my iterations by comparing [0] with [3] and since the 2 sublists are of equal size my function returns "true" which is obviously wrong, since [1] is of length shorter than the rest, hence the result should be "false".

I've tried to solve this by mutating the value of lst, for each iteration, but this again causes a problem if for instance [2] and [3] are same length but [0] and [1] are not, and again it returns "true" even though the output should be "false". (like [[1;2;3];[3;4;5];[6;7];[8;9]])

I can't seem to wrap my head around what I've missed. Since I cant break a loop in F# (at least not in a traditional way like Python), I need to run all my iterations, but I want each iteration to compare with the average of all the previous sublists length (if that makes sense).

What am I missing? :-) I have though of using af List.fold operator to solve the problem, but not sure how I am going to implement this, with the fact that the program also need to check for empty lists.

I can say however I am trying to solve the problem using the metod appropriate to my level og experience thus far. I am sure that several very compact solutions using the pipeline operator |> are available, but I am not yet capable of utilizing these solutions, so I am looking for a simpler perhabs beginners solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

A more functional way to think about this would be

1. If all the sublists are empty, they are all the same length
2. Otherwise, if any of the sublists are empty, they are not of the same length
3. Otherwise, the lists are all the same length if their tails are all the same length

For example:

```
let rec projectOne initList =
    if List.forall List.isEmpty initList then
        true
    else if List.exists List.isEmpty initList then
        false
    else
        projectOne (List.map List.tail initList)
```

Comment: Ah that makes alot of sense thanks! Still trying to allign my thinking more functionally to approach these problems in a clever way.

Comment: @KenLar - Another nice property of this approach is that `List.isEmpty` and `List.tail` are both O(1), and `List.forall` and `List.exists` are short-circuiting (`List.forall` returns false as soon as it detects one item that doesn't match the condition, and `List.exists` returns true as soon as it detects one item that matches the condition). So this function does the minimum possible work to figure out the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another take:

```
let projectOne lst =
    match lst with
    | h::t -> t |> List.forall(fun (l:_ list) -> l.Length = h.Length)
    | _    -> true
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer :-) I got it sorted using several approaches after some time. allways nice to see people using a bit of time helping out in here!

Answer (score 0):

A simple fix of your code could be:

```
let projectOne (initList: int list list) =
    let length = initList.[0].Length
    let mutable result = length <> 0
    let n = initList.Length

    for i=1 to n-1 do
        result <- result && initList.[i].Length = length

    result
```

It still operates on a mutable variable which is undesirable in functional programming and it is inefficient in that it searches all lists even if a wrong length has been found.

---

Another - more functional - solution could be:

```
let haveEqualLength lists =
    let length = lists |> List.head |> List.length
    length <> 0 && lists |> List.tail |> List.tryFind (fun l -> l.Length <> length) = None
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer :-) I got it sorted using several approaches after some time. allways nice to see people using a bit of time helping out in here!